# Blender for web design

Tags: file-format, blend4web

I was wondering if you can use blender to make 3D components for website design? Can they be interactive? What file format should they be exported if you can? And if there is better alternative options for softwares to work with for web design.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, of course you can make interactive 3D for web using such tools as verge 3D

https://www.soft8soft.com/verge3d/

This tool is from blend4web developers and now well maintained.

You can install it as a plugin, and it exports files as glfw, and generates all necessary files to run the 3D scene.

All interactive can be created by internal puzzles editor or javascript. You can manipulate geometry, materials, shape keys, bones in armatures, animation etc.

But you should be aware not to use it everywhere in some reasons:

- All necessary libraries to run the application and project itself may be too heavy to download. It depends on your project, though, but you have to be prepared to 5-20 MB at least
- Running 3D content can be slow on old machines and devices, and uses a lot of power and battery.
- Javascript should not be blocked by extensions.

These common reasons why 3D is used mostly in places where it's worth it: product configurators, games, curiosity projects etc